# How do I specify a file path for a sonar checkstyle exclusion in a maven pom?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, checkstyle

I have a multi-module Maven project. I added a checkstyle exclusion file in one of my lowest level POM files and specified the `<sonar.checkstyle.filters>` with a relative path for that POM, `src/sonar_config/checkstyle.suppressions.file`. When I built the module from its home directory that worked fine.

When I compiled the (great-grand-)parent project I got the error `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar (default-cli) on project sdk: Can not execute Checkstyle: cannot initialize module SuppressionFilter - Unable to find: src/sonar_config/checkstyle.suppressions.file -> [Help 1]`

How should I specify the path to the file so that it works correctly from both the low level directory and the parent projects?

Comment: Where did you specify the sonar.checkstyle.filters setting?

Comment: @JeroenHeier I put the property in the pom closest to the violation. When I built just that pom it didn't mind `src/sonar_config...` but when I compiled from an enclosing pom it didn't recognize that path. So I'm trying to figure out how to specify the path in some way that can be recognized from any level.

Answer (score 1):

```
sonar.checkstyle.filters=<module name="SuppressionFilter"><property name="file" value="build/check-style-suppression.xml"/></module>
```

use this property, and specify your own file path, relative to your project root path.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @haozou , and welcome to Stack Overflow. I no longer work for that company, nor with Java, so I can't test your solution, but since you're new I'll give you an upvote anyway. I can't mark it as accepted without testing though.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but it's functional.

`<sonar.checkstyle.filters>
    <![CDATA[<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="${project.build.sourceDirectory}/../../sonar_config/checkstyle.suppressions.file" />
    </module>]]>
</sonar.checkstyle.filters>`

If anyone has a better way to specify this I'm open to it.

I suspect this must be a SonarQube bug, because the simple path I found for a FindBugs exclusion didn't work for my Checkstyle exclusion.